# How to get record Owner using Apex

Tags: apex

What is the simplest way to get the record's `ownerId` from a `recordId` when I don't know the object type of the ID.

Do I need to figure out the object type and then do a dynamic query?

Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Are you saying, you just have the `recordId` information available and not the object type, and you want to fetch the owner information on that record?

Comment: @JayantDas yes that is correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have just a record's Id, then yes you need to build a dynamic query (if you don't know its type).

```
public static Id getOwnerId(Id recordId)
{
    if (recordId == null) return null;
    String soql = 'SELECT OwnerId FROM ' +
        recordId.getSObjectType() +
        ' WHERE Id = :recordId';
    SObject record = Database.query(soql);
    return (Id)record.get('OwnerId');
}
```

---

The above can be made safer by caching the `sObjectType` so you can check its describe fields for `OwnerId`.

```
public static Id getOwnerId(Id recordId)
{
    if (recordId == null) return null;

    DescribeSObjectResult describe = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
    if (!describe.fields.getMap().containsKey('OwnerId')) return null;

    String soql = 'SELECT OwnerId FROM ' +
        describe.getName() +
        ' WHERE Id = :recordId';
    SObject record = Database.query(soql);
    return (Id)record.get('OwnerId');
}
```

Comment: @Robs N.B. not all objects have an owner, so be prepared to try-catch or check an object describe beforehand.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is by using a query. The query don't need to be dynamic. 
Something like this will give you the **OwnerId** for **Accounts**:

```
SELECT OwnerId FROM Account
```

Depending what you want to accomplish you will need to set some type of logic around your code, but in most cases you will need to query to get the OwnerId in order to use it.

If you want to target a specific id or ids you will need to supply those to the query in our to iterate over those records and get you back the Owner or Owners Ids.

Comment: But I don't know the Object type of the ID